# Rough sets in R

Tags: r

Do you know any R packages implementing rough set based methods? I believe the answer is there are no, but maybe I am missing something subtle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick search with [Rseek](http://rseek.org) reveals that there was a talk on this subject presented at the [useR! 2004 conference](http://www.r-project.org/conferences/useR-2004/). The [abstract](http://www.r-project.org/conferences/useR-2004/abstracts/Tsumoto+Hirano.pdf) mentions an R package, however the package does not appear on CRAN or the authors' personal [web](http://www.med.shimane-u.ac.jp/med_info/tsumoto/) [pages](http://www.med.shimane-u.ac.jp/med_info/hirano/).

**Update:** as noted by @ManuParra in the comments below, there is now an R package, [RoughSets](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RoughSets/index.html), implementing algorithms for data analysis using rough set theory.

Comment: Thanks; still, I'll wait some more time before acceptance.

Comment: Use this: http://dicits.ugr.es/software/RoughSets/